# Value Stored During char assignment

Tags: c, printf

For this below piece of code

```
int main()
{
    char a=a;
    printf("%d",a);
}
```

**Why is the output of the above code 8?**

If I change `%d` to `%c`, it prints nothing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`char a = a;` is a self-initialization, which is basically the same as no initialization at all. Therefore, the value of a is undefined. In practice, its value is determined by whatever happened to be stored in memory at the location of the variable before.

The numerical value of the letter a in ASCII or Unicode is 97. The number 8 is just arbitrary garbage. The compiler would, if it respected itself, give you a compile time error, not just a warning.

As things are, you probably didn't even get a warning -.-

Answer (score 2):

You have to assign it like so:

```
char a = 'a';
```

Currently if it's `char a = a;` its undefined which results in the 8.

That's why it doesn't print it when you do `printf("%c",a);`

Fixed code would be:

```
int main()
{
    char a = 'a';
    printf("%c", a);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `char a=a;` should give a compiler warning. "it puts the numerical value of a which is 8." is wrong. `a` is uninitialzed so is garbage. (The question is also whether `a` is already declared when it is used as an initializer of an automatic variable, namely of itsel.)

Comment: Unfortunately, clang in default settings doesn't. These C and C++ people have no respect for their language or their tools whatsoever...

Comment: @PaulOgilvie Fixed

Comment: I wonder how the sloppy everything-goes C people and the radically strict swift people get along inside the llvm project :D

Comment: Voted your post up because now it's correct, and it has code in it :)